# How to remove passed closure from UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift

sorry maybe title not so much informative, so here is my problem

I want to create ThemeManager and apply to all screens, theme can be changed in the app, thats why I added closureList which will fire and update all related screens

```
class ThemeManager {

static let shared = ThemeManager()

private(set) var theme: Theme
private var bindedList: [()->Void] = []

private init () {
    self.theme = AppGreenTheme()
}

func apply(theme: Theme) {
    self.theme = theme
}

func bind(closure: @escaping ()->Void) {
    bindedList.append(closure)
}

func bindAndFire(closure: @escaping ()->Void) {
    bind(closure: closure)
    closure()
}
}
```

here is how I want to use it from any `UIViewController`, or any `UIView`

```
ThemeManager.shared.bindAndFire {
    // here I will get theme changes and update my screen
}
```

so I wanted to know, in this case will I create reference cycle for `UIViewController`, or `UIView`, and which is the best approach to remove closures from the list after parent `UIViewController` or `UIView`, will be removed from memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its safe as long as you pass your `UIViewController` as a weak reference, like so

```
ThemeManager.shared.bindAndFire { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }

    // here I will get theme changes and update my screen
}
```

But `NotificationCenter` is better approach for this to rely on, here is basic `ThemeManager` example

```
class ThemeManager {
    static let shared = ThemeManager()
    static let NotificationName = NSNotification.Name("Notifacation.ThemeManager")

    var theme: Theme!

    func switchTheme(_ theme: Theme) {
        self.theme = theme
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: ThemeManager.NotificationName, object: self.theme)
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(themeDidUpdate(_:)), name: ThemeManager.NotificationName, object: nil)
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
    }

    @objc func themeDidUpdate(_ notification: Notification) {
        guard let theme = notification.object as? Theme else { return }

        // here I will get theme changes and update my screen
    }

}
```

**Update-2** Example NotificationCenter with a closure

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: ThemeManager.NotificationName, object: nil, queue: OperationQueue.main) { [weak self] (notification) in
    guard let strongSelf = self, let theme = notification.object as? Theme else { return }

    // here I will get theme changes and update my screen
}
```

Comment: Thanks, and what is the best way to be notified when UIViewController is removed, to remove also related closure from the  bindedList?

Comment: Thanks, and why its better to use NotificationCenter? to not to handle closure removal process? thanks

Comment: Can I use NotificationCenter but with block based subscription, using weak self there also will not increase reference count correct?

Comment: your pattern is subscribe, publish, unsubscribe, and thats exactly what notificationcenter does

Comment: Yes off course, references passed as weak are safe for closures, coming an example

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the closures with a `struct` that has also has a property you can check for equality and return the value of that property when a closure is added. The view controller can then pass this id if it wants to remove the closure.You can hide the wrapper from the rest of the code. You can also use `UUID` if you don't want to keep track of some counter. You can also use a dictionary to store the closure with the id as the key.

```
class ThemeManager {
    private var counter = 0
    private var closures: [ClosureWrapper] = []

    private struct ClosureWrapper {
        let id: Int
        let closure: () -> Void
    }

    func bind(closure: @escaping () -> Void) -> Int {
        counter += 1
        let wrapper = ClosureWrapper(id: counter, closure: closure)
        closures.append(wrapper)
        return wrapper.id
    }

    func removeClosure(with id: Int) {
        guard let index = closures.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id }) else {
            return
        }
        closures.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Here's version where you don't need to keep track of an id for the closure. It uses `NSMapTable` with weak keys to store the closures. You can pass the view controller as the key and when it is deallocated the passed closure will be automatically removed from the map table.

```
class ThemeManager {
    private let closureTable = NSMapTable<NSObject, ClosureWrapper>(keyOptions: .weakMemory, valueOptions: .strongMemory)

    private class ClosureWrapper {
        let closure: () -> Void
        init(closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
            self.closure = closure
        }
    }

    func bind(from source: NSObject, closure: @escaping () -> Void) {
        let wrapper = ClosureWrapper(closure: closure)
        closureTable.setObject(wrapper, forKey: source)
    }

    func callClosures() {
        for key in closureTable.keyEnumerator().allObjects {
            let wrapper = closureTable.object(forKey: key as? NSObject)
            wrapper?.closure()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so I will need to figure out how ViewController will know and send closure id, if its autoincremented, thanks for reply

Comment: the id is returned when a closure is added. the view controller can store that id

Comment: Yea, but I thought of mechanizm where UIViewController should not store anything, I guess I find out something, and also if I am not wrong, I should call remove in deinit method yes?

Comment: @NarekSimonyan If you really did have a retain cycle, `deinit` would by definition never be called, so you would not be able to break the cycle there.

Comment: Thanks, I dont have a retain cycle, if I will use weak self described in another answer, I just want to figure out where is correct place to remove closure from the list, thanks

Comment: yup, remove closure should be called in `deinit`. I updated my answer and added a way where you won't need to keep track of the id for the closure. It uses `NSMapTable`. I haven't really used `NSMapTable` a lot, so this probably needs some testing